# How to change 0 value to '-' in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

How to change when the value is 0 then '-' in my sql especially the field have value percentage.
Anyone know about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `IF`

```
select IF(Myfield = 0 , '-', Myfeild) from table
```

Answer (score 6):

Try the following Query:

```
select 
CASE (column name) WHEN '0' THEN '-' ELSE (column name) END
from (table name)
```

Comment: Good answer, but you might have to add `ELSE (column name)` before the `END`.

Answer (score 1):

try this query ::

```
SELECT replace('980','0','-') from dual;
```

output:

**`REPLACE('980','0','-')`**

**`98-`**

`REPLACE` function is used to replace the desired **characters** from a `string`

Comment: MySQL does not have `dual` - this is not Oracle

Comment: @mvp mySQL does have `from dual`. It's just neither required (in most cases) nor a table.

Answer (score 0):

try this, this will find and replace the value

```
update [table_name] 
set [field_name] = replace([field_name],'0','-');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this 
    `<?php 
        $query = "Select * from 0 in";
        $result = str_replace('0', '-', $query);
        echo $result;
     ?>`

Comment: u can use preg_match to check for the expression and then replace it

Answer (score 0):

This statement will replace `0` to `-`, and display number as text with percent otherwise:

```
SELECT
   CASE mycol WHEN 0
   THEN '-'
   ELSE concat(mycol, '%')
   END AS pct
FROM mytable
```

Arguably, this is better done on client side, but I leave it to another answer.